# Running Matlab from Java code

Tags: java, matlab, execute

sorry if I ask a simple question but I would like to ask whether it is possible when executing a java source to have code in it which makes an independent Matlab programme run (not only to execute Matlab code in java) ? I think this is also general question whether you can start other programmes in the process of execution of your code in Java.

Thank you.

Best,

M

Comment: Do you want to run an m-file or a MATLAB executable from Java?

Comment: Please have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607933/running-matlab-function-from-java?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I know you can run external Programmes like this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class CommandExection {
public CommandExection(String commandline) {
try {
    String line;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandline);
    BufferedReader input =
    new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    new CommandExection("c:\\Yourprogram.exe");
}
```

Comment: All this code for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandline);`? :)

Comment: This is an example an executable one you do not need to write the entire code if you figure out how to Place it in your code. :-)

Comment: Obviously. My point was that everything other than getRuntime().exec is irrelevant. I agree that it may be useful to redirect the output of the external progam to stdout, but it's not what is asked here. Instead, it might create unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @EitanT: I disagree. If you do not swallow the input and error streams, your external process will likely choke its buffer and die. I think that this example actually needs more including gobbling the error stream and using ProcessBuilder to get the Process. If you don't tell the newbie to do this, they won't.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Upvote for Clarifying My Point.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is indeed a pitfall if the MATLAB process does write something to the output stream. I agree that extra explantion may be helpful, but instead of replicating code, I'd rather keep the answer consice and add a link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13991125/1336150), for example.