# How to use my created Matlab functions in java

Tags: java, android, matlab

I created a function in matlab and now I want to use that function in my android project, I don't know how do this? Please help me(I saw like this uestion on stack but can)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607933/running-matlab-function-from-java take a look at this

Comment: I used matlab integral function in my function also. so how I can it in my android app!