# How to / is it possible to call a matlab finction from a java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, image-processing, lego-mindstorms

To begin with i am using Eclipse as my java IDE. Im doing a robotics project where my robot (the lego mindstorms ev3) travels a room using SLAM (programmed in java) and does some image recognition using a webcam which is attached to it.

So far i have an algorithm in matlab for the image recognition and ive installed the plugin to use the ev3 from eclipse but i need to be able to link these two together.

(I haven't started on the mapping yet so if any one is interested and has any suggestions then that might be helpful to me, thank you in advance)

My tutor tells me that he hasn't heard of matlab being used in eclipse before but i have seen a few people on the internet say they have done it. Ive looked for plugins but i haven't found anything that i could get to work so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

likewise if any one thinks this cant be done but knows an alternative route that i could take for this project then that would also be appreciated to save me spending further hours researching when im on a tight schedule!

Thanks again guys!

Comment: This seems relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607933/running-matlab-function-from-java

Comment: yea ive seen this. its difficult beacuse they were using a matlab function and expecting an output where i just want to be able to run the matlab alongside eclipse but i need it to link through it to communicate with the robot.