# Python Paramiko Client SSH very slow when read stdout

Tags: python, performance, ssh, output, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to control a VM over SSH. When I send any command it executes almost instantly but when reading the output from stdout it take forever.

I get around 5 seconds for a ls to read:

Time to execute command: `0.1445319652557373`

Time to read output: `5.382704973220825`

Here is a snippit:

```
import time
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname="192.168.0.123",
        port=1234,
        username="admin",
        password="admin")

t1 = time.time()
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("powershell -command \"ls -recurse .\"")
t2 = time.time()

t3 = time.time()
print(stdout.readlines())
t4 = time.time()

print(t2 - t1)
print(t4 - t3)
```

Thank you!

Comment: The `exec_command` does not *execute* the command completely. It only starts the execution. It's actually the `readlines` that waits for the command to complete. See [Paramiko with continuous stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25260088/850848). Or do you have any proof that Paramiko is actually reading the output slower than other SSH clients? How long does it take to execute `ssh admin@192.168.0.123 powershell -command "ls -recurse ."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout.readlines()` Is reading all lines before your subprocess finishes and sends EOF to your main process. If you want to read line by line when available, then do `for line in exp.stdout`, the file object allows you to iterate over each line as its feed through the pipe. Otherwise it would probably be better to use `stdout, stderr = Subprocess.communicate(None)` as the communicate method uses a better system calls to read data from a Subprocess (like epoll, select, poll).

Comment: How can you use `Subprocess.communicate` with SSH?

Comment: see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227791/ssh-with-subprocess-popen

Comment: OK, but that's a completely different approach (and inferior to the one taken by OP).