# calling matlab from python script always displays matlab information even with nodisplay flag

Tags: python, matlab, command-line

My machine: ubuntu 18.04, run with python 3.7.1 and matlab 18b, in python it is:

```
import os

os.system('matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash -r "Mymat;quit;"')
```

and in Mymat.m it is

```
function X2 = TFOCS_LS()
  a = 1; b = 2;
  X2 = a+b;
end
```

Even I set that `-nodisplay` flag, in the terminal it will still print something like below in the command line. How to suppress this information printout?

```
                                                         < M A T L A B (R) >
                                                Copyright 1984-2018 The MathWorks, Inc.
                                           R2018b Update 2 (9.5.0.1033004) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                                            January 5, 2019

 
For online documentation, see https://www.mathworks.com/support
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
```

Comment: `-nodisplay` turns off the graphics display, has nothing to do with terminal I/O. I don’t think it is possible to turn off the MATLAB welcome message.

Comment: I tried this on 18a and I don't see the MATLAB welcome message

Comment: That is not what those command-line args do, but you can pipe the stdout from the Matlab process into /dev/null. This won't help if you need the stdout to view your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments
`-nodisplay` is just to run Matlab headless without graphical output and does **not** disable the commandline or shell output.

-If you don't want any output at all from matlab you can use `&>/dev/null` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command-using-bash) to dump the output or write it to a file.

-If you want to remove the Matlab "welcome Header" forever, you can edit the matlabrc.m file and remove it there, wich might be against the matlab Terms & Conditions. For more information please look [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/24677-is-there-a-way-to-suppress-the-startup-help-message-when-running-matlab-from-the-command-line).

-A 3rd Option is to remove the Header using the `tail` Function of Linux like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518072/suppress-start-message-of-matlab/1518129).

This is not part of your Question, but could be handy if you plan to use more Matlab Funcions in Python: There is a [Matlab Engine API](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html), that makes it possible to run Matlab funcions without using `system`. (And also is a lot faster, as you don't need to start Matlab every time you want to call a Matlab function)